# Override anchor onclick

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, anchor

There are file download links connect to a `servlet`. Documents should open in a new tab. I want to use `a:visited` behavior on these links. Somehow using `target="_blank"` don't mark them as `visited`. Therefor I removed `target="_blank"` from the `anchor` and used `onclick` event.
Within this `onclick` event handler I used `window.open(url,'_blank');`. This works as excepted with `visited`.
But if the `servlet` unable to serve the document (ex: document may not be there) `anchor` opens a new tab ***and also opens the download link in parent window***.
I want to prevent this. I tried `onclick="return onClickHandler(id);"` with return `false`.
If I use that, those links do not mark as `visited`.

How browser knows that requested link doesn't have a file. Is there any thing I should return from the `servlet` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you did return false, it hasn't been visited. The best you could probably do is style it.

```
$(this).addClass('visited');
```

css

```
.visited {
    color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Yes, only for that session.

Comment: can get help from the return value of window.open(); ?

Comment: Here is the code for checking 404 status, whitout using jquery:

function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}

Comment: Above 404 code was really helped me. Actually the idea. This wasn't the solution but this is a part of it. I used $cookie object and added those ID's to save visited links and did some other stuffs to keep the app in a stable window. Thanks!